# Validate Request in MVC5

Tags: web-config, ckeditor, asp.net-mvc-5

I am getting excpetions in MVC5 while uploading HTML Content. I have specified [HttpPost, ValidateInput(false)] on my ActionMethod as well as specified httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" in the web.config of my application but still it is throwing exceptions. Any suggestions to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by marking the Controller with ValidateInput(false)